# ROS on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ros2, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Does anybody have installed ROS on Ubuntu 21.04 hirsute?
Could you please guide me through the process of ROS installation on Ubuntu 21.04

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380207/ros-on-ubuntu-21.04/) by [Amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/76063/amigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which ROS version/distribution do you want to use ? As far as I know there is no ROS version supported for ubuntu 21.04 yet.

See reps for more details:

For ROS1: https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html

For ROS2: https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html

You can also check distributions link:

For ROS1: http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions

For ROS2: https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Releases.html

---

Originally posted by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) with karma: 195 on 2021-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/76063/amigo/) on 2021-06-15**:
Hi @Youssef_lah, thanks for your answer, I've installed fresh copy of Ubuntu 21.04 on my desktop computer just to work with ROS. I wonder when would there be a release of ROS for this version of Ubuntu.. I wanna get into learning more about ROS, unfortunately it is not possible at this point of time :(

**Comment by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on 2021-06-15**:
You can simply delete ubuntu 21.04 and install 20.04 then install ROS1 noetic or ros2 (foxy or galactic), then start learning/practicing, you don't have to wait for a new version for 21.04.

**Comment by [Amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/76063/amigo/) on 2021-06-16**:
thank you @Youssef_Lah for the advice.. I'll install Ubuntu 20.04 on my machine, I'm also new to Robotics. Could you please suggest me a good book on Robotics.. I'm a software engineer who is also interested in Robotics. Currently I'm taking Stanford's(Oussama Khatib sir's) "Introduction to Robotics". I would be grateful if you could suggest a book :)

**Comment by [Youssef_Lah](https://answers.ros.org/users/41510/youssef_lah/) on 2021-06-16**:
I started learning ROS by reading/practicing this book:
http://wiki.ros.org/Books/ROS_Robot_Programming_English

**Comment by [Amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/76063/amigo/) on 2021-06-16**:
Thank you sir. Take care & Have a nice day! :)